# split word by special character

Tags: regex

I want to find all pairs of words separated by ":"
Let me explain with examples:

```
aa:bbb
```

(output) match1=> aa; bbb

```
aa: bbb ccc
```

(output) match1=> aa; bbb ccc

```
aaa: bbbbb ccc ddd: eeee
```

(output)match1=> aaa; bbbb ccc
  (output)match2=> ddd; eee

---

I found 2 regex:

1)`\s*([a-z0-9]+)+\s*\:\s*([a-z0-9]+)+`

2)`(.*)\:(.+?)(?=[a-z0-9]*\s*:)`

The first found all occurance but not work in this case for example(word separated by white space like bbbbb ccc):

```
aaa: bbbbb ccc
```

But work in this case:

```
aa: bbb ccc:dd eeee:fff
```

The second not found all occurance but work in this case:

```
aaa: bbbbb ccc
```

Comment: Based on your examples, why would you do it with regexes? Please read [why you shouldn't use regexes when there are better ways](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/113237/when-you-should-not-use-regular-expressions). Splitting the examples with regular `split(':')` actions  is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

To answer with a regex despite it may not be the best way to do it:

`(\w+ *):([\w ]+)(?!\w* *:)`

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/cW0uV6/1)

I make two capture groups, 1 before the `:`, one after.

To be sure my second capture group doesn't take the "key" of the next one I use a negative lookahead to ensure I can't match the format of a key just after (any word or space character just before a :)

To match the keys exactly I use `\w+ *` for at lest one char followed or not by one or more space and for the negative lookahead `\w* *:` to be sure I can't match a single `:`, nor `a:` or `a :`

for the values I use a character class, any word character (`\w` is `a-zA-Z0-9_`) or space at least once.